# Routes not working in react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to work with react router v4. I have a application where I have two pages: Login page and App Page. In my app page I have three sections: Header, sidebar and content section. This is what I want

1. Landing page should be Login page
2. Once user clicks login button, user should land to App Page. (For testing I haven't included user authentication)
3. Now in my App page, I can show one of the 3 components (which I have already made) based on what user clicks on sidebar. So Sidebar and header should always be visible and content division should change it's component based on what user click on sidebar.

This is how I have setup my routes right now

```
class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <main>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
                    <Route exact path="/app" component={App}>
                    </Route>
                </main>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
          <Sidebar/>
        <main>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/trivia" component={TriviaPanel}/>
            <Route exact path="/image" component={ImagePanel}/>
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

MenuPanel.js (from where I go to trivia and image)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const styles = require('./sidebar.css');

class MenuPanel extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="navbar-side">
                    <div className="tessact-logo"></div>
                    <div className="navbar-item active" onClick={() => this.props.toTriviaPage()}>
                        <a className="navbar-item-link"><span className="fa fa-comment"></span> TRIVIA</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="navbar-item" onClick={() => this.props.toImagePage()}>
                        <a className="navbar-item-link"><span className="fa fa-picture-o"></span> IMAGES</a>
                        <div className="navbar-item-inside">
                            <a className="navbar-item-inside-link">PERSONSS</a>
                            <a className="navbar-item-inside-link">BRANDS</a>
                            <a className="navbar-item-inside-link">OBJECTS</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="navbar-item">
                        <a className="navbar-item-link"><span className="fa fa-tags"></span> KEYWORDS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    toTriviaPage: () => push('/app/trivia'),
    toImagePage: () => push('/app/image')
}, dispatch)


export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MenuPanel)
```

I want TriviaPanel to be the default view when landed to App. Currently I land to login page and when I click to login, App page is not working in the manner it should. I can't see anything apart from sidebar and header, which also gets disappear when I click something in sidebar (trivia link).

How should I achieve this? In react router v3 there was a nice option of childroutes. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: not sure if it's convention or not for RRv4, but you could add another `Route` to your `Switch` in `App.js` - `<Route component={TriviaPanel}/>` as a catch-all

Comment: This itself is not working. Whole App component is wrong that I know for sure. I don't think that is the way to nest in RRv4.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `App`. You are doing the nesting correctly, but your paths are wrong. Looking at `Root` the `App` component lives on `/app`. So your nested routes should ALSO include the `/app` prefix in their paths:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
          <Sidebar/>
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/app/trivia" component={TriviaPanel}/>
            <Route exact path="/app/image" component={ImagePanel}/>

            {/* Catch-all route for TriviaPanel */}
            <Route component={TriviaPanel}/>
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Ah, apparently this is a known issue with react-router-redux: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md#blocked-updates

You need to wrap your connected component with the `withRouter` HOC from `react-router-dom`:

```
// before
export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MenuPanel)

// after
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
export default withRouter(connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MenuPanel))
```

Comment: I tried this. By you way TriviaPanel comes as default now. But whenever I click something on sidebar which should either take me to the ImagePanel or TriviaPanel, Everything disappears. Which means the lines <Route exact path="/app/trivia" component={TriviaPanel}/>
            <Route exact path="/app/image" component={ImagePanel}/> are not working

Comment: What does `<main/>` do? I'm gonna guess that something in your setup is causing the error. If you are on `/app/trivia` you should be seeing the component. Can you post the code for the `<Sidebar/>`? What do your `Link`s look like?

Comment: Added. Please have a look

Comment: @ApurvG thanks for the update, didn't know you were using react-router-redux `push()` method. Context changes everything :)

Comment: Nothing changed after I updated the MenuPanel as per your answer

Comment: Are you sure my App.js is correct in terms of routes? I really don't think so?

Comment: The only I can see that's not normal is `<main>`. Try removing `main` and see if it works. Not sure what else it could be. You may want to change your component to use `Links` instead of doing a `push`.